# Dynamic Instance Specific Django Field Creation

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a situation where a User model can have 'X' number of unique fields that need to be added.  These fields need to have queries run on them, so I cant just add a field containing a string of JSON to it.  For example, one user could look like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField()
    profession = models.CharField()
```

And the next could be:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField()
    badge_number = models.IntegerField()
```

Like I said above, these unique fields must be queryable. HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mean unique in the Django/DB sense, you can try to use the postgres [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield), a field that stores a JSON and is queryable.

Example code from the documentation:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the querying:

```
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
...     'breed': 'labrador',
...     'owner': {
...         'name': 'Bob',
...         'other_pets': [{
...             'name': 'Fishy',
...         }],
...     },
... })
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'breed': 'collie', 'owner': None})

>>> Dog.objects.filter(data__breed='collie')
<QuerySet [<Dog: Meg>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether these are totally arbitrary "any combination of these fields may be present," whether there are subsets that would make the possible combinations easier to deal with, or even whether the full set of possible fields is even predefined, but you probably have at least one of the following options.

1. Write a single User class (or user profile class) with all possible fields on it, with fields that may be on one user but not another set as `null=True`.
2. Have multiple user types extending User (or one of its superclasses) with different fields.
3. Write a custom Manager to (expensively) unpack a JSON or other multi-value field when querying a single User model to manually remove your custom fields from the query and apply them to the preliminary result set.
4. Have a user profile model linked to your User class that's then subclassed to add various combinations of possible fields.

Inheritance can turn this situation into a real pain, so that's something I would avoid... for the situation you've described, I think #1 is likely the best fit. If `null=True` isn't acceptable for your use case, your options become a lot less palatable, readable, and maintainable.

*Note: The answer from @henriquesalvaro came in while I was writing this, and seems superior to the following options. I'm going to post this anyway in case JSONField isn't something you can use.*